# Quiero que el contenido flexible se envuelva y no se encoja

Tags: css, responsive, flexbox

Tengo días con un problema con flexbox y es que tengo un contenedor que tiene varios div anidados con imagenes y uso las propiedad display flex y flexwrap para que se envuelva y las imagenes se posicionen una debajo de otra  al disminuir el tamaño de la pantalla pero lo que hace es encojerse en vez de envolverse. Le tengo aplicar la propiedad flexbox a todos los hijos porque si no se desordena el codigo. Espero me puedan ayudar

```
<body>
    <div class="main">
        
        <div class="main-container">
        
        <div class="main-cover">
        
        <figure  class="cover">
        
            <img src="imagen.jpg" alt="contenido">   <img src="imagen.jpg" alt="imagen">
                <div class="cover-text"> <span><h2 id="subtitle-cover">Playa Azul</h2><br>  <h3>Falcon</h3><br><p> definicion del contenido</p></span></div>
         <button><a href=""><span>Ver playa</span></a><i class="fas fa-umbrella-beach"></i> </button>   
         
        </figure>
        
        
        <figure class="cover">
        <img src="imagen.jpg" alt="playa las maritas "> 
        <img src="imagen.jpg" alt="playa las maritas "><div class="cover-text"> <span><h2>Playa Las Maritas</h2><br> <h3>Edo Sucre</h3><br><p> definicion del contenido</p></span></div> <button><a href=""><span>Ver </span></a></button><i class="fas fa-umbrella-beach"></i>
        
        </figure>
        
        <figure class="cover">
            <img src="imagen.jpg" alt="imagen ">    
            <img src="imagen.jpg" alt="imagen "><div class="cover-text"> <span><h2>Playa Las Maritas</h2><br> <h3>Edo Sucre</h3><br><p> definicion del contenido</p></span></div> <button><a href=""><span>Ver </span></a></button><i class="fas fa-umbrella-beach"></i>
            
            </figure>
        

        </div>  
        </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>

<style>
.main-container {justify-content: center; width: 100%; margin-top: 5%; margin-bottom: 5%;flex-wrap: wrap; flex-grow: calc(2);  }

.cover {border: 0.3em solid white;}

.main-cover {  position:absolute;display: flex;  width:100%;height:420px;justify-content: center; position: relative; }

.main-cover img:first-child {filter:blur(5px); opacity: 1;width: 100%; height: 100%;z-index:1;}
.main-cover img:nth-of-type(2) {width:30%; height: 50%;z-index:2 ;position: relative;bottom: 90%;left:10%; border: 0.3em solid white; }
.fa-umbrella-beach{color: white;font-size: 100%;margin-right: 50%;z-index: 3;} 

.cover-text{z-index: 3;position: relative;font-family: roboto; bottom:145%; width: 45%; left: 45%; height: 20%; } 

span {color: white; text-decoration: none; }

span h2 { font-size:100% ;font-style: bold; }

span h3 {font-size:100%; font-style: italic;text-align: center;}

span p {font-size:100%;text-align: justify;}


figure button {width: 150px; height: 40px;background: #2EECA0; border-radius:33px ;z-index: 4; position: relative; bottom: 100%;color: white;left: 50%;}

figure button span {font-family: roboto;font-size: 1em;color: #02234E;font-weight: 700;}
</style>
```

Comment: Ahora mismo tienes flex-wrap en el main-container pero no el display: flex, en cambio en el main-cover tienes el display: flex pero no el flex-wrap: wrap (que es lo que hace que cuando no quepan en el container se redistribuyan), prueba a poner display: flex y flex-wrap: wrap en el main-cover, para que se apliquen esos dos estilos al mismo contenedor.

Answer (score 0):

1. Primero se recomienda poner la etiqueta ***style*** dentro del elemento ***head***
2. Creo que el button no debería llevar un *position: relative;* sácaselo
3. La clase *.main-cover* tiene que llevar un ***flex-wrap: wrap;*** y te recomiendo agregarle un ***align-items: center;***
4. Te recomiendo agregarle el siguiente código a la clase *.cover*

```css
 .cover {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
     padding: 20px;
     width: 300px;
     height: 350px;
     border: 0.3em solid white;
}
```

5. Y por último es buena práctica *resetear* los estilos del navegador, lo puedes hacer con el siguiente código (ponelo al inicio del elemento style):

```css
* {
     box-sizing: border-box;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
 }
```

Espero que mi aporte te sea útil :)